# Process Asciidoc with Gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, asciidoc

I want to convert some [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoctor.org/) .adoc file into HTML and use Gradle for that.

I am new to Gradle. I have found https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin
and below is `build.gradle` that is about to do that, but with my level of Gradle I don't know what to do next

```
// https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'Bintray Asciidoctor repo'
            url  'http://dl.bintray.com/content/aalmiray/asciidoctor'
        }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:0.7.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'asciidoctor'

// append below the line: apply plugin: 'asciidoctor'

asciidoctor {
    outputDir = new File("$buildDir/docs")
    options = [
        eruby: 'erubis',
        attributes: [
            'source-highlighter': 'coderay',
            toc: '',
            idprefix: '',
            idseparator: '-'
        ]
    ]
    //+
    //sourceDir = new File(".")
}
```

Comment: If studying the plugin docs and general AsciiDoctor docs doesn't help, perhaps check out some other builds that are already using this plugin (Griffon, Groovy, etc.).

Comment: Maybe my Ruby example will help: [Guardfile](https://gist.github.com/craibuc/9323879)

Answer (score 3):

I got my setup working with [this tutorial](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/install-and-use-asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/). You don't have to explicitly set the JCenter repository as it can be used with `jcenter()` as you already have.

I don't know what's up with the asciidoctor plugin, but I had to use version 0.5.0 as 0.7.0 failed on internal error and 0.6.0 failed on some Ruby problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have [Gradle installed](http://www.gradle.org/installation).

Then, make sure you have files with filenames ending in `.adoc`, `.asciidoc`, `.asc`, or `.ad`. They should be in the `src/asciidoc` subdirectory of your project.

Then, run Gradle from a command line with the command:

`gradle asciidoctor`